# My Javascript running into errors with vaadin NoLayout annotations requirement

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt, layout, vaadin7

My vaadin(7.4.6) application running into errors saying "c**annot read property 'NoLayout'".**

This is happening because my application is having a window that being created through javascript only, and vaadin expects the properties annotated with **@NoLayout annotation**.

Exception is being thrown from the **property.isNoLayout()** in below code of ApplicationConnection class :-

```
if (onlyNoLayoutUpdates) {
    Profiler.enter(
            "updateConnectorState @NoLayout handling");
    for (String propertyName : stateJson.keys()) {
        Property property = stateType
                .getProperty(propertyName);
        if (!property.isNoLayout()) {
            onlyNoLayoutUpdates = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    Profiler.leave(
            "updateConnectorState @NoLayout handling");
}
```

It seems to me that the problem is due to connector (that is created automatically) is having the SharedState object in it as "JavascriptComponentState" and above logic is trying to find the property in "JavascriptComponentState" that's not available in there, it should search this property in my state class "MyAppComponentState".

Is it a problem with connector?

Comment: Please share you code regarding this "a window that being created through javascript onl".

Comment: @HenriKerola :- One thing before this, can we create a custom connector for our javascript component, if yes then can you please point me to any example ?